# Detect initial network status in a hybrid application

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am implementing `cordova-plugin-network-information`and detecting the status connection works correctly, but I am not getting the initial network status, only works when the connection change.

Any improvement or clue to get the real status when the app is initialize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem like this:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", () => {
        if (navigator.connection.type === Connection.NONE) {
            variableContainingYourNetStatus = false;
        } else {
            variableContainingYourNetStatus = true;
        }
    });
```

Note the TypeScript-syntax. In JS you might want to change the lambda into a `function`.

Basically when `deviceready` is fired, the plugins are initialized as well. So this is the right time to check your network status and set the variable that contains the status.

Comment: Adapting your response to my app.. I agree the idea  ;-)  thank you!!